# You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1 libdrm.so.2 libdrm.so.2 libdrm.so.2

Tags: software-installation

This message appears when I try to launch steam on Linux:

> You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libGL.so.1 libdrm.so.2 libdrm.so.2 libdrm.so.2

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should start with your OS/product/release details;  as *deb* packages are built for a specific release and we don't know any of your specific OS/release details.  Are you using Ubuntu?  What Ubuntu product?  What release of that product?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same promblem, this helped me:
https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/1736635023062287934/?l=latam

Try these:

```
# install apt-file to search for files in packages
sudo apt install apt-file

# add i386 architecture for Steam i386 libraries (32 bit required)
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

# update packages including i386 architecture packages
sudo apt update

# search for each missing file for i386 architecture
#  (in this case searching for libGL.so.1, libdrm.so.2)

apt-file search libGL.so.1 -a i386
# On Debian the package list is:
# libgl1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
# libgl1: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
# libgl1-nvidia-legacy-390xx-glx: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/legacy-390xx/libGL.so.1
# libgl1-nvidia-tesla-418-glx: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/nvidia/tesla-418/libGL.so.1
# primus-libs: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus/libGL.so.1
# In this case the required library on Debian is libgl1-nvidia-legacy-390xx-glx for NVidia hardware,
# libgl1-nvidia-tesla-418-glx if we have to NVidia Tesla (very expensive, most likely not on a user machine),
# primus-libs if we want Bumblebee Optimus with NVidia,
# libgl1 for other hardware

apt-file search libdrm.so.2 -a i386
# On Debian the package list is:
# libdrm2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2
# libdrm2: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
# In this case the required library on Debian is libdrm2

# install packages that are most likely to be needed based on what is returned previously

# For some Ubuntu, in case in the list was returned 'libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx' then we install it
sudo apt install libgl1-nvidia-glvnd-glx:i386

# On Debian we install the missing packages based on the previous lists (you might want other packages if it doesn't work)
# 1. For NVidia hardware without Bumblebee:
sudo apt install libgl1-nvidia-legacy-390xx-glx:i386 libdrm2:i386
# 2. For NVidia Tesla (very expensive, most likely not on a user machine):
sudo apt install libgl1-nvidia-tesla-418-glx:i386 libdrm2:i386
# 3. For NVidia hardware with Bumblebee Optimus:
sudo apt install primus-libs:i386 libdrm2:i386
# 4. For other hardware:
sudo apt install libgl1:i386 libdrm2:i386

# Reload libraries (create dynamic links for new libraries so that libGL.so.1.7.0 points to libGL.so.1, for example)
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).